# How to use the special "xml" namespace prefix with XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

I'm using `XElement` to build an XML document in C# and I'm trying to set

```
<myEelment xml:space="preserve">
```

Here's my current attempt:

```
myElement.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("space", "xml"), "preserve");
```

but it comes out like this:

```
<myEelment p4:space="preserve" xmlns:p4="xml">
```

I understand how this is going wrong - my code is using "xml" as a namespace URI when I want to use as a namespace prefix. My problem is that AFAICT the "xml" namespace prefix is somehow implicit and doesn't actually have a namespace URI associated with it. So how can I generate attributes with the namespace prefix "xml"?

Comment: `XNamespace.Xml.GetName("space")` and BTW `xml` prefix associated with `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard namespaces are available as properties on the `XNamespace` class.  Use that.

```
var myElement = doc.Descendants("myElement").Single();
myElement.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve");
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew there would be a really simple answer but I just couldn't figure out a way to google it :). I don't really like the way MS have overridden the "+" operator so that you can add a namespace to a string and get a name - it seems an abuse of the concept of "+" and gives the impression to a casual reader that you're casting the namespace to a string and then doing a string concatenation. For this reason I prefer @PetSerAl's syntax.